# Hidden Markov Chains - Is there a typo in this lecture?

Tags: markov-process, hidden-markov-model

Lecture in question: https://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~jcorso/t/CSE555/files/lecture_hmm.pdf
Slide #6 shows this graph:
[image]
Slide #7 gives these probabilities:
[image]

**Is P(Dry|High) = 0.3 on slide #7 a typo?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a typo. From the diagram, $P(Dry|High) = 0.6$